# SpecFlow. Couldn't load file or assembly

Tags: bind, .net-assembly, specflow

I'm tring use 2 projects in SpecFlow.

The first project has name: FrontEnd.Tests
There are SpecFlow's Features and Steps (Definitions)

The second project: FrontEnd.Tests.Extended
So, In second project I added in App.config

```
  <specFlow>
    <unitTestProvider name="MsTest" />
    <stepAssemblies>
      <stepAssembly assembly="FrontEnd.Tests" />
    </stepAssemblies>
  </specFlow>
```

To use steps definitions from 1st project.
But I get error:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'FrontEnd.Tests' or one of its dependencies.

Projects are in the same directory.

Comment: See if [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/255669/how-to-enable-assembly-bind-failure-logging-fusion-in-net) helps.

Comment: I made this already :)

Comment: Then you should have added the information from that log into your question.

Comment: After that I got: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'FrontEnd.Tests' or one of its dependencies. 

Another information I found extra

Comment: Is your FrontEnd.Tests.Extended project referencing the FrontEnd.Tests project?

Comment: And did you verify that FrontEnd.Tests.dll is in the same build folder as FrontEnd.Tests.Extended?

Answer (score 1):

Try this, add a file with name specflow.json and reference your assemblies in there:

```
{
  "stepAssemblies": [ 
    { "stepAssembly": "FrontEnd.Tests" } 
  ]
}
```

Comment: This literally does the same thing as the XML in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to put `.dll` on the end of the file name:

```
<specFlow>
  <unitTestProvider name="MsTest" />
  <stepAssemblies>
    <stepAssembly assembly="FrontEnd.Tests.dll" />
  </stepAssemblies>
</specFlow>
```

Answer (score 0):

For those in .net core you need to exclude the ".dll" extension and the file is specflow.json and set the properties like so:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For those working with .netCore and VSCode and/or dotnet-cli you need to do 2 things:

First: specify the additional assembly in the specflow.json file (just the name of the file without .dll extension)

```
{
   "stepAssemblies": [
      { "assembly": "AssemblyWithStepDefs" }
    ]
}
```

Second: modify the project file (.csproj) so the specflow.json file is always copied to the output directory

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="specflow.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
```